# Confused with python syntax involving API

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, printing, syntax

Confused on python syntax as I am just learning it (coming from c++). Using bybit.com API.

I am trying to execute two commands:

```
1. print(session.get_wallet_balance(coin="USDT"))
2. print(session.latest_information_for_symbol(symbol="BTCUSDT"))
```

[image: Bybit Request/Response Example 1.]

[image: Bybit Request/Response Example 2.]

According to Bybit's api, the request example (1 & 2) each deliver their own response example. (Included 2 pictures for each request example. The response delivers multiple items and I am only looking to have only specific ones displayed. For the first command (1.), I only want the `available_balance` to print. It successfully does, however when I try to print only `last_price` for the second command (2.), it does not print the last price and returns an error.

This is how I have it, in which (1.) works by just printing the number, but not (2.):

```
1. print(session.get_wallet_balance(coin="USDT")['result']['USDT']['available_balance'])
2. print(session.latest_information_for_symbol(symbol="BTCUSDT")['result']['last_price'])
```

Is there also a way for me to take the value from `'last_price'`  and assign it to a variable. The price of a crypto coin is changing every second and does not have a fixed price. I would require the variable with the value of `last_price` to include in a formula.

Comment: 1. If you're coming from c++ then you know there is a way to assign to a variable. A quick google search would answer that for you. Like this, https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables.asp.
2. You say you get an error but you dont post what error you are getting, so hard to help you.
3. Please dont post a screenshot of code or the response you get. Makes it much harder for people to look through and help you out. Post the code and response in a code block.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because the result part of the second response is a list containing (multiple) dictionaries.
So you would need to acess it like this:
`print(session.latest_information_for_symbol(symbol="BTCUSDT")['result'][0]['last_price'])`